# Simplifying log

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been told that $10^{\log_{10}(x)}$ is simply x

I have also been told that $10^{\log_{10}}$ are the inverse of each other and cancel each other out but am having trouble understanding this.

Can somebody kindly explain how the above is simply x and how the $10^{\log_{10}}$ are inverses?

Thank you.

Comment: They are inverse eash other by definition! How do you define $\log_{10}$?

Comment: put the dollar sign symbol before and after each math expression: 10^{\log_{10}(x)} $\rightarrow 10^{\log_{10}(x)}$

Comment: @YunusMurad that's what you wanted to type ?

Comment: @ Isham Yes thank you. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by definition

$$y=\log_{10} x\iff  10^y=x\iff 10^{\log_{10}x}=x$$

and more in general

$$c=\log_{a} b\iff  a^c=b\iff a^{\log_{a}b}=b$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes it makes sense now. Thank you to all those that edited and commented.

Comment: Well done! You are welcome, Bye!